# Special Binary Tree

Tags: binary-tree

What is the name of the binary tree (or the family of the binary
trees), that is balanced, and has the minimum number of nodes
possible for its height?

Well this is special kind of tree not the AVL tree.

Comment: Don't you mean maximal number of nodes for it's height?

Answer (score 2):

if the  binary tree is balanced then, it height is a function of its nodes (n).   height  =   log<sub>2</sub>n.  so a balanced tree don't have a  range of heights.

Comment: And what about RB-tree then? It's balanced but may have quite different heights of its leaf nodes (basically 2x difference at maximum) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree .

Comment: a RB-tree is allowed to be nearly  balanced , that is way there is a range of  it heights  (is also in the Wikipedia entry : "the tree is roughly balanced"

Answer (score 1):

The minimum number of nodes a completely balanced binary tree can have for height d is 2^(d-1)+1. As far as i know this type doesn't have a name.

The maximal number of nodes is 2^d. This is called a complete tree. All layers are completely full and each node has either 2 or zero childern(implied).

Answer (score 0):

<del>Red-black tree?</del>

Any one from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree#Implementations?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the binary tree (or the family of the binary trees), that has the minimum number of nodes possible for its height is a linked list :D